# AD User receiving duplicate emails of any email sent to distribution list

Tags: exchange-2003

I have a user who receives two copies of any email sent to a distribution list. The distribution list only includes the user once in the members, and there aren't any distribution lists added as a member of this distribution list.

We are using Exchange 2003 and he is using Mac Mail. The emails are duplicated in both webmail and Mac Mail so it doesn't appear to be a client issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe two considerations:

1. Under the addresses for the mailbox, any chance that there are two email addresses identified which are also on distribution list?
2. Any chance that another mailbox/client is performing a forward rule to the subject mailbox?

Comment: My bet would be 2).  Vote++